# File operation progress dialog

Tags: c++, windows, progressdialog, explorer, windows-shell

Windows provides standard component - progress dialog. It was invented in Windows XP. Progress dialog can be created via CoCreateInstance call with interface IProgressDialog. Windows Vista provides another (new) UI for progress dialog. One need to create progress dialog with interface IOperationsProgressDialog to get new UI. There is the one component (CLSID_ProgressDialog): it supports both interfaces and UIs. IOperationsProgressDialog interface is recommended to use.

I've developed namespace extension. it supports drag & drop. I use scenario to transfer data from my NSE:

- IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf -> IDataObject
- IDataObject::GetData -> FILEDESCRIPTOR, FILECONTENTS
- FILECONTENTS -> IStream
- IStream::Read -> data to transfer

FILEDESCRIPTOR reports that my NSE requires progress UI (FD_PROGRESSUI). Progress dialog is shown while files are copied. This progress dialog has UI which is provided by IProgressDialog interface. I need explorer to use progress dialog with IOperationsProgressDialog's UI but I don't know how to force explorer do it. I provide IDataObject and IStream only. NSE is designed for Windows 7 but progress dialog has old UI. How can I get new progress dialog UI during copying from my NSE to explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can `QueryInterface` whether the provided object implements `IOperationsProgressDialog` as well, but you should be prepared to handle `E_NOINTERFACE`.

Comment: I report option FD_PROGRESSUI. it means that I'd like to have progress dialog while data is transferring. I doesn't create progress dialog myself, explorer does it. I don't control transfering process, explorer does it. Explorer reads my data by portions and updates progress dialog. My NSE is just the source of data.